# getting value count of a an array element respective to each row with python

Tags: python, arrays, preprocessor

**input data**
this is my input data from each array i need its respective count ,if it is not present then 0 will be

```
   ID                     array
0  20  [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1  34     [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
2  55        [6, 8, 9, 2, 1, 6]
3  66        [3, 4, 7, 7, 8, 1]
```

**output**

```
    ID        array              1  2   3   4   5   6   7   8  9
0   20  [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 3  2   1   1   1   0   0   0  0
1   34  [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]    1  2   1   1   0   1   1   0  0
2   55  [6, 8, 9, 2, 1, 6]  1    1  1   0   0   0   1   0   1  1 
3   66  [3, 4, 7, 7, 8, 1]  1    0  0   1   1   0   0   2   1  0
```

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean (welcome to Stack Overflow), but we're not here to do your homework for you. You have to make an attempt. Try something, if you get errors, do some research, and if you still can't figure it out, post what you've tried (the code), the error(s) you're getting, and what you researched.  Good luck.

Comment: It seems like `pandas df` will pandas solution work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here's one way via `pandas`:

```
df1 = df.explode('array')
df = pd.crosstab(df1['ID'], df1['array'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line of code for each row of you dataset :

```
[name_list.count(element) for element in range(1,10)]
```

where list_name is the list you want to pass as argument and count the recurrences